# std::variant access raw memory buffer

Tags: c++

I'm working on an networking program.
I'm planning to use std::variant as a type-safe alternative to union.
My variant definition `std::variant<std::uint8_t, message_struct_t> msg;`
I'm getting error in statement `std::memset((void *)std::get<std::uint8_t>(msg), 0, sizeof(message_struct_t));`

Error:

MSVC

```
error C2664: 'void *memset(void *,int,size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_First' to 'void *'
```

Clang16

```
Program stderr
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_variant_access'
  what():  std::get: wrong index for variant
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
```

If I modify my variant definition to `std::variant<void *, message_struct_t> msg;` which is an ideal case all API working on buffer read, write, std::memset, std::memcpy, etc. use `void *` as an argument type to access buffer.
In this case I get error

In MSVC

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE400D1A6A (vcruntime140d.dll) in CommonClasses.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

In Clang16

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_variant_access'
  what():  std::get: wrong index for variant
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>
#include <cstring>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    float b;
} message_struct_t;

typedef union
{
    std::uint8_t data;
    message_struct_t msg;
}message_union_t;

std::variant<std::uint8_t, message_struct_t> msg;

int main()
{
    
    message_union_t data;
    data.msg.a = 10;
    data.msg.b = 10.23;
    std::cout << "a : " << data.msg.a << "\tb : " << data.msg.b << std::endl;
    std::memset(&data.data, 0, sizeof(message_struct_t));
    std::cout << "a : " << data.msg.a << "\tb : " << data.msg.b << std::endl;
    
    message_struct_t struct_msg;
    struct_msg.a = 20;
    struct_msg.b = 20.34;
    msg = struct_msg;
    auto s = std::get<message_struct_t>(msg);
    std::cout << "a1 : " << s.a << "\tb1 : " << s.b << std::endl;
    
    std::memset((void *)std::get<std::uint8_t>(msg), 0, sizeof(message_struct_t));
    auto v = std::get<message_struct_t>(msg);
    std::cout << "a1 : " << v.a << "\tb1 : " << v.b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Link:

https://godbolt.org/z/M4bKq11f7

Comment: `(void *)std::get<std::uint8_t>(msg)` converts a single byte (uint8) to a pointer. That must be UB. I am not sure there's a non-UB way to use `memset` here. Even memsetting over `(void *) & std::get<std::uint8_t>(msg)` looks like UB to me.

Comment: Are you trying to use the type-safe `variant` to do the Undefined Behaviour you were doing with unions? That's going to be a pain.

Comment: Don't use **mem** functions in C++. They are unsafe and constitute dens for bugs. For single objects use proper constructor, for collections(arrays, containers...) use `std::ranges::fill` or `std::fill`. You can check `equal` and `copy` for other use cases too.

Comment: @Red.Wave It's pretty common to `memcpy` to/from network packets in C++. And `memset`'ing zero then overwriting with values in some fields isn't a *bad* practice.

Comment: @Caleth That's wrong practice. As I mentioned use `fill` for that purpose. For C programmers **mem** functions are the tool. In C++ just **don't**. There are lots of caveats and bugs related to these relics and no performance gains.

Comment: @Red.Wave when you want to copy the object representation of a type defined in some network protocol into/out-of a local variable, `mem` functions are correct. `std::copy` is for copying objects, `memcpy` is for copying bytes. If the protocol specifies that it needs bit-pattern `0xCD` in particular places, writing bit-pattern `0xCD` isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Caleth `copy` covers that case too. Don't make exceptions to the rule. `memcpy` is the den of stinging bugs. Don't touch, unless you have to do it in pure C. Don't worry about performance; `std::copy`( I'd rather use `std::ranges::copy`) peaks the fastest implementation. `<ranges>` is a rich toolbox for composing network buffered data using range adapters. `memcpy` is just a misfit on those senarios, while `copy` mixes quite easily.

Comment: @Red.Wave you have to be careful with casting to correctly use `std::copy` to do bytewise copying. I'm not worrying about performance, I'm worrying about expressing "manipulate these N bytes" as operations that are clearly "manipulate N bytes" and not "manipulate objects". The only "stinging bugs" that `memcpy` has over `std::copy` in the context of bytewise copies are shared with `memmove`, i.e. requirement for non-overlapping ranges.

Comment: @Caleth `sizeof` can go wrong for a simple typo. I don't see why you insist on using such irreadable, error prone syntax. As just one example on N consecutive bytes, investigate `std::span<std::byte>`.

Comment: @Red.Wave Are you saying that given `std::span<std::byte, N> data = get_from_network(); message_struct_t msg;` one should `std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::span(&msg, 1).as_writable_bytes().begin())` over `memcpy(&msg, data.data(), data.size())`? I disagree

Comment: @Caleth No. Your network buffer should typically be implemented as a `std::vector`. If you need type-punning, use `std::bit_cast`; but the source and destination should be **trivial** types. The process involves using a `std::array<std::byte, N>` as the medium; network side `copy`s in and out of the array and presentation side `bit_cast`s. Both operations are cheap enough to optimize. Plus side is higher margin for errors.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm not talking about type punning, I'm talking about starting from an object of some trivial type (`message_struct_t` here), and writing the object representation of that to some range of bytes, or vice-versa. I don't see any issue with using `memcpy` for that. "Your network buffer should typically be implemented as a std::vector." Only if you are in control of the whole network stack. Some of the time all you have is `size_t writeBytes(std::span<std::byte>);` and `std::span<std::byte> readBytes(size_t);`.

Comment: @Red.Wave I also mentioned the example where you have some type with padding bits within its representation, and you need to have control over the values of those bits. You can't do that using assignment, you *have* to `memset` or similar

Comment: @Caleth you are doing type-punning. What's the definition of biwise copying a single element to/from unrelated type(byte sequence)?

Comment: @Red.Wave Ok, you can reasonably call that type punning. Still, `std::bit_cast` doesn't help when you've got a `std::span<std::byte>` and a `message_struct_t` and want the bytes of one written to the other. You want something *very similar* to [cppreference's possible implementation of `std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast#Possible_implementation)

Comment: @Caleth read what I wrote about type punning again. Don't mix things up. There's 2 cases that a C programmer might use `memcpy`: 1. Array copy, which is covered by `copy`. the network buffer can be viewed as `span<byte>`. 2. Type punning: exact number of bytes are read from net buffer into an array then `bit_cast`ed into result. The reverse is also possible: `bit_cast` from source to fixed array and then copy into net buffer. No `memcpy` needed in either case.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the implementation. It might be anything. Because it is provided by the platform programmer and guaranteed to follow standards and not produce bugs. If you directly use `memcpy` in your code, that would be a problem. The final output of compiler is machine code. Do you write machine code in your programs? Do you use assembly code in your programs?

Comment: Assuming type-punning from a buffer, the combined result of `bit_cast` and `copy` might be optimized to a single assembly `move` instruction or `memcpy` or anything faster, depending on size of data and platform capabilities.

Comment: @Red.Wave I did read what you said about type punning. "Array copy is covered by `copy`" And I already said `std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::span(&msg, 1).as_writable_bytes().begin())` is *to me* less clear than `memcpy`. And to `bit_cast`, you have to have the exact bytes in an array, and not as e.g. a `span` pointing into a *segment* of some array elsewhere

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't check the source and destination type; If used on none-trivial types, result is UB. Your usage of `span` is incorrect too. `as_readable_bytes` does puning in an undesirable fashion. You're exactly doing what you shouldn't. The net/file buffer is a sequence of bytes, so in general it can be represented by `span<byte>`. Explicit use of address_of operator(`&`) in your snippet is the first sign of trouble. Stay away from pointer syntax/semantics for as long as it takes.

Comment: The plus side of `bit_cast` is exactly the size limitation and its contraint for **trivial** types. That's why I mentioned that in reading from buffer has 2 steps. First copy exact number of bytes from `span` to `array`, then `bit_cast` to result. The copy part will still be prone to wrong size(but there are generic solutions for that); but type safety is gauranteed by `bit_cast`: e.g. you won't overwrite the **vtable** of polymorphic types, because it won't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a union to get the underlying object representation of your struct to memset it. You can't type-pun through either a union or a variant, the difference is trying with a union results in undefined behaviour, whereas the variant is defined to throw. That's what is meant by "type-safe" when talking about `std::variant`.

```
int main()
{        
    message_struct_t msg;
    msg.a = 10;
    msg.b = 10.23;
    std::cout << "a : " << msg.a << "\tb : " << msg.b << std::endl;
    std::memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(message_struct_t));
    std::cout << "a : " << msg.a << "\tb : " << msg.b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[See on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4eKjn5sc6)

Comment: std::memset is even not required here,
just write "msg = {};"

Comment: @jls28 I'm assuming that `memset` is a placeholder for the use cases OP's actual program have which interact with the object representation of `msg`